# Send pdf file as attachment to text message

Tags: sms, pdf, attachments

Maybe this is a naive question, but I was wondering if I could attach a pdf file to a text message. I have a Sony Xperia M4 Acqua running on Android 5.0.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't. Text messages are 7-bit ASCII, 160 characters restricted messages. An MMS might allow you to attach a file but I'm pretty sure there are size limits there. I recommend sending an Email or uploading it to a personal cloud and sending the link to the file.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You can only send small images and audios, but that would turn the SMS into MMS. Don't you like emails?